# When to use comma after time adverbs

Tags: adverbs, commas

I am trying to say sentences like:

> Then by doing this thing, this happens
>
> Now after selecting this option, this happens
>
> By doing this, now we can do this

Should they get comma after "then" and "now":

> Then, by doing this thing, this happens
>
> Now, after selecting this option, this happens
>
> By doing this, now, we can do this

Comment: Read your sentences out loud, trying to emulate natural pauses or gaps between the words. This should indicate where your commas are. [Example 1](http://vocaroo.com/i/s1UiR9azUnvf) [Example 2](http://vocaroo.com/i/s1aCNj3ycnIt).

Comment: @JMB I thought there is a rule! if I can use both, I prefer the first one, cause I think "then by doing this" is a complete phrase

Comment: Actually the complete phrase is "then...this happens" and "by doing this" is parenthetical.  *Then, having done that, this happens.* or *When we do that, this happens.*

Answer (score 2):

Both are good, although I think the second examples are slightly better. What you are saying is :

Then (by doing this thing) this happens

Now (after selecting this option) this happens

By doing this (now) we can do this